# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space while deploying GWT application to Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

------------ Deploying frontend ------------

Preparing to deploy:

```
Created staging directory at: '/var/folders/14/l6tq2_1x17s0p1bcq5nsqphwthd17d/T/appcfg2818721238209183883.tmp'
```

Scanning for jsp files.

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

This error occurs while deploying my application to google app engine from eclipse.

Comment: Increase heap value of java. What is current heap value?

Comment: It's not a problem when I am running it on my laptop. The problem is while deploying it to GAE-

Comment: Yes it's server issue where you are trying to deploy application. Check heap memory of system where you are trying to deploy and increase this.

Comment: I am trying to deploy it on Google App Engine using "Deploy to App Engine" option in GWT on right click on my project.

Comment: @MiyaG - Sorry, but this is _not_ a remote issue, it's a local one. App Engine did not have a chance to run this program yet (i.e. fire up a Java VM and execute the code), because the deployment was aborted.

Comment: @carora3: This is a different Java program that throws this error - it's not the app that you are writing. It works on your local machine, so you need to increase heap space for Java as suggested in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Either your project uses to much heap space within Google App Engine...

> Try to reduce the memory your application needs or purchase an
>   instance which is more expensive...
>
> Select another "Frontend class" as described here (the more memory the
>   more heap):
>
> https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings

**... or if the error occurs while deploying (your case)** you need to increase the heap space java is allowed to use on your host system. Read more here:

> [Increase heap size in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java) ...

... and for eclipse specific instructions see here:

> https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse

Comment: This is a deployment error, not a run time error. So it's definitely the local issue.

Comment: You are correct! I still posted every possibility since the comments where a bit confusing in the rush ;). It seems like the OP things that it does not have something to do with his local setup since he is deploying. But this is ofc not correct. I edited my post so that the important things regarding his problem are highlighted.